# Does facebook use comet for notification

Tags: facebook, reverse-ajax

we know that Facebook use, for chatting messages, long polling technique to meet "Real-time" needs.

Does it use same technique for notifications ??

Comment: what is comet? your question is not clear.

Comment: comet means long polling